# Facebook iOS SDK invitable_friends v2.4

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite-friends

I have a Facebook iOS app, and I'd like to allow my users to invite their Facebook friends to my app. The proper endpoint is /{userId}/invitable_friends which is working well. But towards the bottom of that doc page, they recommend implementing a "search box" to filter the results, yet they don't offer any example of how to do this. I've searched around and haven't found anything.

It doesn't appear as though you can pass additional params for filtering the results. Obviously I can filter the results after the fact, but that's not scalable since the API only returns ~20 users at a time. That limit is modifiable (I believe), though it's of course not wise to bump it too high.

So how can I build a search box interface if I can't pass the search text to the endpoint? I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.4
i look up this tutorial...